# Get the user email firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-permissions, user-permissions, shopify-app

Im trying to do something like this

[image: shopify screenshot]
i have found this pop up dialog in a few apps like shopify app  and discord app , once you open sign up or login page dialog pop up with all possible emails.

Now my question how to achieve something like this without asking the user for contact permission.

My current Code is :

```
private void addAdapterToViews() {
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getActivity()).getAccounts();
    Set<String> emailSet = new HashSet<String>();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (EMAIL_PATTERN.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            emailSet.add(account.name);
        }
    }
    binding.autoemail.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new ArrayList<String>(emailSet)));
}

private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }
    if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        Snackbar.make(binding.autoemail, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            addAdapterToViews();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working fine for me once the user try to type any letters in email `edittext` if permission is granted.

Comment: that to focus full grant the permission and not show permission dialog

Comment: is there's way to display the user emails without permissions like shopify app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credentials API to retrieve sign-in hints, such as the user's name and email address.

On Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) and newer, your app does not need to request any device or runtime permissions to retrieve sign-in hints with the Credentials API

```
HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
        .setHintPickerConfig(new CredentialPickerConfig.Builder()
                .setShowCancelButton(true)
                .build())
        .setEmailAddressIdentifierSupported(true)
        .setAccountTypes(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)
        .build();

PendingIntent intent = mCredentialsClient.getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest);
try {
    startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(), RC_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0);
} catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not start hint picker Intent", e);
}
```

[HintRequest Builder Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-hints#retrieve_sign-in_hints)

Comment: this is the best and easiest way of getting user emails thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not what you are looking for, but I really recommend that you take a look to [Authentication with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) and the helper library [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth). They have all that boilerplate already implemented and it is really easy to config, customize and setup.

Comment: Right now i have backend with server already sorted but this can be useful in some situations,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to get access user confidential information (like email id ) without runtime Permissions.

Comment: if you install shopify POS you will be able to see all of your Emails without accepting any permission, and i just checked in settings app permission and theres nothing on

Answer (score 0):

So far what i have found out is using google service to get all of the user emails without any permission with the following code :

```
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;
```

Inside `OnCreate()` or Button click :

```
AuthUI.SignInIntentBuilder builder = AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder();

if (getSelectedTosUrl() != null && getSelectedPrivacyPolicyUrl() != null) {
    builder.setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls(getSelectedTosUrl(), getSelectedPrivacyPolicyUrl());
}
builder.build();
startActivityForResult(builder.build(), RC_SIGN_IN);
```

And to get results

```
 @Nullable
    private String getSelectedPrivacyPolicyUrl() {

        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    private String getSelectedTosUrl() {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            handleSignInResponse(resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResponse(int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        // Successfully signed in
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//            startSignedInActivity(response);
//            finish();
            Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(response));

        } else {
            // Sign in failed
            if (response == null) {
                // User pressed back button
//                showSnackbar(R.string.sign_in_cancelled);
                Log.e(TAG, "Sign-in error: failed");

                return;
            }

            if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
//                showSnackbar(R.string.no_internet_connection);
                Log.e(TAG, "Sign-in error: no net");
                return;
            }

//            showSnackbar(R.string.unknown_error);
            Log.e(TAG, "Sign-in error: ", response.getError());
        }
    }
```

But my problem is that the user email dialog open in pre made sign in activty, but i would like to use my own.
Any tips ? here is the source [google library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo)